# Android ActionBar view background height

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-bitmap

How to change background bitmap height for a custom view in action bar ?!
My code:

**actionbar_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_bg"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="false"
    android:filter="false"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

**custom_actionbar.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"><RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/background"
android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/list" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate" /></RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

and **How should be**

[image]

Comment: Changing android:layout_height="50dp"> in your custom_actionbar.xml doesn't change anything?

Comment: @Tardo No, it doesn't change anything

Comment: Try setting a custom dp size instead of android:layout_height="wrap_content", in the beginning of your custom_actionbar.xml

Comment: @tardo without changes

Comment: Can you please provide your activity code on your actionbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your image. It can be with very big paddings. Try to check it.